# Unity Время бездействия

Tags: android, c#, unity3d

Какие есть варианты распознать бездействие игрока? допустим если 15 секунд ничего не делает не нажимает, тогда какое то действие выполнять ?

Comment: Как вариант, пробовали на любое действие поднимать флаг/счётчик? Соответственно, когда такой флаг/счётчик не меняется слишком долго - это и можно называть бездействием.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 float idle_lim = 30.0f; // допустимый лимит в секундах
 float last_ui = 0.0f;
 bool idle = false; // текущий статус idle

 void FixedUpdate() { 
    if ( (Input.anyKeyDown ) { // реагирует на любое действие пользователя - мышь, клава, тачскрин
       if ( idle ) {
          idle = false;
          // что делать в случае возврата пользователя из idle
       } 
       last_ui = Time.time;
    }
    if ( ( Time.time - last_ui ) > idle_lim ) { 
        idle = true;
        // инициировать тут что необходимо при входе в idle
    } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const float timeout = 10.0f;
float countdown = timeout;
bool idle = false;
...

if (!idle) {
    if (moveDir != Vector3.zero)
        countdown = timeout;

    if(countdown <= 0.0f) {
        idle = true;
        // Started-being-idle code here.
    }
    countdown -= Time.deltaTime;
}
else {
    if (moveDir != Vector3.zero) {
        idle = false;
        countdown = timeout;
        // Stopped-being-idle code here.
    }
    // Still-being-idle code here.
}
```

Comment: не все бездействия - это только движения

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. У меня нет ничего что связано с векторными значениями, собственно одни UI кнопки